# ODE and separations of variables: what about $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Considering the following ODE:
$$ y'=f(x)g(y)$$ as long as $g(y) \neq 0$, I can divide by $g(y)$, and obtain
$$ \frac{y'}{g(y)}=f(x)$$
and by solving
$$ \int \frac{dy}{g(y)}= \int f(x)dx$$
I eventually find a solution $y$ on a domain $I$ (for the sake of clarity, let's put $I=(a,b)$) such that $g(y(I)) \neq 0$. But what if, for example, $y(a)=0$ is well defined, $y$ in $a$ is continuous and with a continuous derivative such that $y'(a)=0$, and $g(y(a))=0$? Can it even be possibile? In this case the method above is not working anymore in $a$, but since our original equation was $y'=f(x)g(y)$, would $y$ be a solution on $[a,b)$ and not only on $(a,b)$?

These may sound like trivial questions, but I'm currently studing ODE and their resolution methods and I'm having an hard time grasping all the concepts. Hopefully everything makes sense and it's written in proper English. Thanks everyone!

Comment: There is no problem with $g(y)$ being zero in some points. If $g(y_0)=0$ the constant function $y=y_0$ is a solution to the ODE. It boils down to uniqueness... Only the constant solutions can take a value that is a zero of $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the method you describe, you can (in certain cases) find a solution $y(x)$ to your differential equation on an interval $I = (a,b)$ such that $g(y(x)) \neq 0$ for $x \in I$. After finding the solution, it may happen that there exists a larger interval $J \supset I$ such that we can extend $y$ to $J$, while $y$ still satisfies the differential equation $y'(x)=f(x)g(y(x))  $ (even though we may have $g(y(x))=0$ for points in $J$).

There is no problem with this: the requirement $g(y) \neq 0$ is neccesary to find a solution by seperation of variables, but there is no reason why a solution to the differential equation must always satisfy $g(y) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Just a small clarification, to answer both to you and @PierreCarre. Using a similar notation to the one I used above, if $y(x_0)=y_0$ and $g(y_0) = 0$, then $h(x)=y(x) \text{ if } x > x_0$ and $h(x)=y_0 \text{ if } x \leq x_0 $ is still a solution. Meaning that in any case I always have to check if, for $\lim_{x \to a^-}y(x)$, $y(x)$ "behave nicely" enough to find a larger interval, am I right?

Comment: @Wallace yes, after using separation of variables, you can always check if there is a larger interval to which you can extend the solution, so that it is still a solution. You can try this with $y' = y^{\frac13}, y(0)=0:$ the interval you obtain by seperation of variables is not all of $\mathbb{R}$, but you can extend the solution to all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (I should have made the initial condition $y(0)=1$)

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is a zero of $g$, by Picard's method the solution is $y(x)=0$.